# Ruby: Error in minitest to destroy user

Tags: ruby, minitest, fixtures, destroy

I am a newbie to ruby and am just creating my first test suite.

When writing a minitest to destroy a user I get the following error:

```
ERROR["test_should_destroy_when_logged_in_as_a_admin", UsersControllerTest]
test_should_destroy_when_logged_in_as_a_admin#UsersControllerTest ActionController::UrlGenerationError: 
No route matches {:action=>"/users/608331937", :controller=>"users"}
```

The test reads the following:

```
        def setup
        @user_destroy = users(:destroyme)
        @user_admin = users(:admin)
    end

    test "should destroy when logged in as a admin" do
        log_in_as(@user_admin)
        assert @user_admin.admin?, "not admin"
        assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
            delete user_path(@user_destroy)
        end
    end
```

and fixture:

```
admin:
 name: Matthias Havenaar
 email: my@mail.com
 password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
 admin: true

destroyme:
 name: Destroy Me
 email: destroy@me.com
 password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
 admin: true
```

It seems like something goes wrong with the user ID or user_path. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: try to replace this `delete user_path(@user_destroy)`  with `delete :destroy, id: @user_destroy`

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the solution. Does it have to do with the fact that this is a controller- rather than an integration test?

Comment: Not actually becoz The way you have written path is what which we generally define in controller but minitest has his own way to define paths.

Comment: added the answer please accept if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I hope this will work.

**Replace**

```
delete user_path(@user_destroy)
```

**With**

```
delete :destroy, id: @user_destroy
```